# Can we make our own Identifier (id) in mongodb as mysql

Tags: php, mongodb

Can we make our own Identifier (id) in mongodb as mysql, How? I am using php script for communicating with mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has primary key `_id` that has an [unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) index in top level of all documents. If you insert a document without `_id` key specified, MongoDB will create it for you and set it as [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

You can set "_id" field in your document to anything you want as long as it is unique, immutable and not an array.

If you want to creat an auto-increment field, you can check the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

Comment: Thank you, and is this _id would work as autoincreament orderly?

Comment: ObjectId contains UNIX timestamp (in it's first part) but you should check ObjectId docs (provided in the link in my answer) for more details if your app require id with strict insertion order.